# How to Use jQuery in Grails 3.0

Tags: jquery, grails

I am trying to figure out how to get jQuery running in my Grails 3.0 application. I attempted adding the jQuery dependency like so in my build.gradle

```
runtime "org.grails.plugins:jquery:1.11.1"
```

When I did that, the application failed to build. I have not changed anything in my application.js file, so it still looks like this:

```
//= require jquery-2.2.0.min
//= require bootstrap
//= require_tree .
//= require_self

if (typeof jQuery !== 'undefined') {
    (function($) {
        $('#spinner').ajaxStart(function() {
            $(this).fadeIn();
        }).ajaxStop(function() {
            $(this).fadeOut();
        });
    })(jQuery);
}
```

Inside of my gsp pages I have tried both:

```
<g:javascript>
          $( document ).ready(function() {

                $( "#a" ).click(function( event ) {

                     alert( "Thanks for visiting!" );

                 });

           });
</g:javascript>
```

and

```
<g:javascript library='jquery'>
            (function($){
                $( document ).ready(function() {

                    $( "#a" ).click(function( event ) {

                        alert( "Thanks for visiting!" );

                    });

                });
            })(jQuery);
</g:javascript>
```

The first resulted in an error stating that '$' was not defined and the second said that jQuery was not defined. So how am I supposed to run jQuery inside of a gsp page?

Comment: That is a grails 2 plugin. There is no grails 3 jquery plugin. Instead you should look into asset-pipeline

Comment: I see. Thanks. I just needed to add `<asset:javascript src="jquery-2.2.0.min.js/>` to main.gsp. I thought was already being pulled in, since in the source on the page it said it was there.

Answer (score 7):

grails 3 comes with jquery. You must set up in your gsp page like this:

```
<head>
    <meta name="layout" content="main" />
    <asset:javascript src="application.js"/>
    <asset:stylesheet src="application.css"/>
    <title></title>
</head>
```

the asset for "application.js" invokes JQuery for your page. Regards.